# Python - if/else vs dict mapping?

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

I have a method that returns reference value from one of the objects. Before calling a method I don't know from which class object will be returned. And different class reference attribute is different, but it is used for same purpose.

It looks like this:

```
def _get_ref_object(self):
    """"Return reference object: invoice or expense"""
    self.line_ids.ensure_one() 
    line = self.line_ids[0]
    invoice = line.move_line_id.invoice
    if invoice:
        return invoice
    else:  # If there is no invoice, it means it is expense
        return line.expense_id
```

Now when I have exact object I can return various reference value from various attributes. 
For example if I need reference invoice or expense number, for invoice I need to return `number` attribute's value and for expense, `name` attribute's value.

But for this to work I need to call if/else again to know which object was returned, like:

```
def get_reference(self, ref):
    obj = self._get_ref_object()
    if ref == 'number':
        if obj._name = 'account.invoice':
            return obj.number
        else:
            return obj.name
```

Now if I would want to get reference for another attributes, I would need to do same if/else checks. But I started thinking, maybe use dictionary to map all of this and then just access attribute using `ref` as key? By performance wise, is it faster to just access dictionary's value instead of doing if/else? And if it is a good practice in such cases?

**Update** Implementation with dict mapping:

```
_ref_map = {
    'account.invoice': {'ref': 'number'},
    'hr.expense.expense': {'ref': 'name'}
}

def get_reference(self, ref):
    obj = self._get_ref_object()
    attr = _ref_map[obj._name][ref]
    return getattr(obj, attr)
```

Comment: I would imagine dictionary lookups are somewhere between "slightly" and "a good deal" faster than if/else constructs, but I'm not sure this is what you should be doing anyway. Why don't you subclass your current type to create `Invoice` and `Expense` objects that know what they are?

Comment: Performance-wise, it does not matter, the case here is one of letting the code express the intent clearly and, in doing so, being maintainable. Unless you have already identified this specific function as a bottleneck, this matters more than performance, especially for such a trivial case. To provide a useful answer, it would be great to have more context. One could think of using the `Strategy` pattern for instance, or just plain inheritance.

Comment: @AdamSmith What do you mean subclass my current type? What I need is some general method that would get me reference I want without knowing from which object.

Comment: @Andrius I guess I don't understand your use case. The method will absolutely know what object is calling it. Since it doesn't, I'm assuming that the type that "owns" this method isn't as specific as it ought to be. If you could post the whole class I might be able to make a more specific suggestion.

Comment: How would your solution with dictionary work? I don't see how it can get of the `if` checks.

Comment: @Prayag I written implementation with dictionary. It is working, I just don't know if it is a good idea. Well it actually take less code to use this solution. And if would need to check another attributes, I would only need to update dictionary instead of creating if/else for every case.